# Clean way to remove an identical nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript

can you give me some feedback about my approach to remove an idential element from following data structure?

```js
const items = {
  'Sun Mar 07 2021': [
     { id: 2 },
     { id: 1 }
  ],
  'Sat Mar 06 2021': [
     { id: 1 } // remove me
  ]
}

const id = 1 // filter by id 1
const newDate = 'Sun Mar 07 2021' // filter by newDate

let oldDate = ''
// Find the duplicate date and 
// save it in oldDate to splice it afterwards
Object.keys(items).forEach(date => {
  items[date].forEach(item => {
    const match = item.id === id
    if (match && date !== newDate) {
      oldDate = date
    }
  })
})

const idx = items[oldDate].findIndex(el => el.id === id)
// remove the old item from matched array
if (oldDate) items[oldDate].splice(idx, 1)
```

I think it can be simplified or solved differently. Unfortunately I can't get any further, do you have any ideas?

Comment: @radarbob I believe this question is appropriate for Code Review. Any reason it should be moved to StackExchange? Especially, which SE site will it belong to instead of Code Review?

Comment: You code does not work, your example works only due to luck.. `Array.splice` does not take a function as an argument. Because you have not included the delete count argument the line `items[oldDate].splice(item => item.id === id)` will delete all items in the array `items[oldDate]`

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it can be simplified or solved differently.

That's good intuition. That's called a *code smell*. Something "smells" funny, off, or wrong but not sure what it is. Pay attention to that feeling!!

> Unfortunately I can't get any further

This is an even stronger code smell.

> do you have any ideas?

- Re-examine the `date` object design.

  - `date` and `IDs` should be in one object
  - Put the date objects into an array. Array is designed for easy handling of multiple objects.
  - Using Array's provided methods should eliminate external variables and functions.

---

This code demonstrates overall structural changes after fixing the objects. Algorithm details not shown.

```
const dates = [
  { date : 'Sun Mar 07 2021',
     IDs : [ 1, 2 ]
  },
  { date : 'Sat Mar 06 2021',
     IDs : [ 1 ]
  }
]

const dupeDate = { date : 'Sun Mar 07 2021', IDs : [ 1 ] }

dates.forEach( date => {

  if( date.date === dupeDate.date ) return;

  if( date.IDs.includes( dupeDate.IDs[0] )) { 
    // algorithm details here. Should be function calls as much as possible, 
    // not dozens of lines of nested, nested code.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback. I have the freedom to change the data structure and I am ready to do so.